# How to create Alphabetic pagination with range?

Tags: pagination

Currently, I am trying to create an alphabetic pagination with ranges for a custom post type on a custom field using [this code](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/424/alphabetical-posts-glossary/) from kathy is awesome. I have gotten everything working except for the range aspect of it. Such as A-E, F-H and so on. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used [that](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/424/alphabetical-posts-glossary/) code, now you have a custom taxonomy called 'glossary', what you need to show the range is a custom query like

```
new WP_Query( array(
  'tax_query' => array(
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'glossary',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => range('a', 'e')
     )
   )
) );
```

The problem is **how to perform this query with a url**?

You can make use of an [endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint), something like

```
add_action('init', 'add_glossary_range_endpoint');

function add_glossary_range_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'letters', EP_ROOT );
}
```

Doing so, when you visit the link `http://example.com/letters/a-e/` a variable 'letters' is added to the query and you can intercept it and use for your scope using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'glossary_range_query');

function glossary_range_query( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get('letters') ) {
     $letters = explode('-', $query->get('letters') );
     if ( count($letters) == 2 ) {
        $tax_query = array(
          'taxonomy' => 'glossary',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => range($letters[0], $letters[1])
        );
        $query->set('tax_query', array($tax_query) );    
        $query->set('letters', NULL );     
     }
  }
}
```

Now you have to visit the *Settings->Permalinks* page on your backend and save changes to flush rewrite rules and then you are done.

Now probably you have to create a fucntion to show the link to range pages, something like:

```
function get_glossary_range_url( $from = 'a', $to = 'z' ) {
  return home_url( '/letters/' . $from . '-' . $to . '/' );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for the late replay. Been swamped. Most of all thanks so much for your reply. I haven't had time to test this yet but will this week and see if I can get this working and post the results. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, well finially I have had the chance to work on this. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work the way it was need so, the easy work around was that I just created the taxonomy in the cpt. Then gave it the range needed for each term within the admin. Add the links into the template from the term the admin chooses. Not really the way I wanted to do it but it works.

Comment: I would like to add here about sorting taxonomy terms with Alphabetic Pagination plugin. It simply works with pre_get_posts and where clause hook. It's query efficient technique as well.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/alphabetic-pagination